# How to mod_rewrite query string which includes path and parameters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, query-string

My website uses a rather complicated query string parameter: Its value is a path including parameters.

For SEO (Search Engine Optimization) etc. I'm now attempting to mod_rewrite shortened versions...

- `example.com/path/c1/d1/e1.html?x=x1&y=y1`
- `example.com/path/c2/d2/e2.html?x=x2&y=y2`
- `example.com/path/c2/d3/e4.html?x=x5&y=y6`

...to the currently required...

- `example.com/path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1&y=y1`
- `example.com/path/?param=a/b/c2/d2/e2?x=x2&y=y2`
- `example.com/path/?param=a/b/c2/d3/e4?x=x5&y=y6`

So the goal is to...

1. get rid of the fixed part (`?param=a/b/`) to shorten the address and
   don't have two `?` in the visible address
2. preserve the query string value's necessary variable path components (like `c1/d1/e1` or `c2/d2/e2` or `c2/d3/e4`)
3. add `.html` to the final part before the query string value's `?` to make the folder structure appear 1 level less deep
4. preserve the query string value's necessary variable parameters (like `?x=x1&y=y1` or `?x=x2&y=y2` or `?x=x5&y=y6`)

After hours of research and attempting lots of things that did not work, I signed up here to request your advice on how to solve this mess. Would you please be so kind to assist?

Edit / additional infos:

- After the fixed string `/path/?param=a/b/` it is always 3 variable path segments like `c1/d1/e1`.
- These variable segments can contain alphanumerical characters `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9`, dash symbol `-` and bracket symbols `(` and `)`.
- Same applies to the parameter values (x1, y1). Additionally, y1 can contain percent symbol `%` due to URL-encoding.
- Using two question marks (one to start the query string and the other as part of the parameter value) looks invalid but works.
- The actual file that handles the request is `/path/index.php`.

Comment: Is `path` a fixed string? There is always then 3 additional path segments eg `c1/d1/e1`? What characters can `c1`, `d1` and `e1` contain? Likewise, what can `x1` and `y1` contain? `/path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1&y=y1` doesn't look like a valid endpoint - what is the actual file that handles the request? eg. `/path/index.php`?

Comment: `/path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1&y=y1` - How exactly are _you_ interpreting this? It looks like you are perhaps expecting this to be a single URL parameter value `param` that contains `a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1&y=y1`? However, as written that would be two URL parameters `param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1` and `y=y1`? The last `&` would need to be URL encoded as `%26` in the request to be interpreted as a single URL parameter.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply!

Yes, "path" is a fixed string, the whole "/path/?param=a/b/" is a fixed string.

Yes, after that fixed string it is always 3 variable path segments like "c1/d1/e1".

These variable segments can contain alphanumerical characters a-z A-Z 0-9, dash symbol "-" and bracket symbols "(" and ")".

Same applies to the parameter values (x1, y1). Additionally, y1 can contain percent symbol "%" due to URL-encoding.

Yes, including two questionmarks in the URLs looks invalid but works. 

Yes, the actual file that handles the request is /path/index.php.

Comment: I wasn't really querying the two question marks (the 2nd `?` becomes part of the query string), it was the last `&` that is in question - should this not be URL encoded? As written, it's 2 URL parameters (which looks incorrect) as noted above. Although this might depend on how you are parsing the URL (letting PHP do it, or are you doing this manually)?

Comment: Yes, it's written as two URL-Parameters, but 
domain.com/path/index.php
takes the whole query string 
"?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1&y=y1"
and simply removes "?param=" to curl
other1.com/a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=x1&y=y1
and output the content at domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

# REDIRECT: /path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=1&y=y1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/path/(?:index\.php)?\?param=a/b/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)\?(x=[^&]+&y=[^&]+)\s
RewriteRule ^(path)/(?:index\.php)?$ /$1/%1.html?%2 [R=302,L]

# REWRITE: /path/c1/d1/e1.html?x=x1&y=y1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(x=[^&]+&y=[^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^(path)/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)\.html$ $1/index.php?param=a/b/$2?%1 [L]
```

**The first rule redirects** any *direct* requests for the "old" URL of the form `/path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=1&y=y1` (`index.php` is optional) to the "new" canonical URL of the form `/path/c1/d1/e1.html?x=x1&y=y1`. This is for the benefit of search engines and any third party inbound links that cannot be updated. You must, however, have already changed all your internal links to the "new" canonical URL.

By matching against `THE_REQUEST` (as opposed to the `QUERY_STRING`) we avoid a redirect loop by preventing the rewritten URL from being redirected. `THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the request headers and is not changed by other rewrites. For example, `THE_REQUEST` would contain a string of the form:

```
GET /path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=1&y=y1 HTTP/1.1
```

This is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have tested that this works OK, in order to avoid potential caching issues.

**The second rule *internally rewrites*** requests for the "new" canonical URL, eg. `/path/c1/d1/e1.html?x=x1&y=y1`, back to the original/underlying URL-path, eg. `/path/index.php?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=1&y=y1`. The `&` before the last URL parameter is intentional un-escaped (ie. URL decoded) as discussed in comments.

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences refer back to the captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Whereas the `%1` and `%2` backreferencs refer to the captured groups in the preceding *CondPattern*.

> These variable segments can contain alphanumerical characters `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9`, dash symbol `-` and bracket symbols `(` and `)`.

I've used a more general (and shorter) subpattern in the regex above which will match more characters, but is arguably easier to read. ie. `[^/]+` - matches anything except a slash and `[^&]+` - matches anything except a `&`.

If you specifically wanted to match only the allowed characters then you could change the above subpatterns to `[a-zA-Z0-9()%-]+` or `[\w()%-]+` which also matches underscores (`_`).

---

> **UPDATE:** x and y are just examples for parameter names, but in reality there can be lots of different parameter names.
> the parameters have more than a single character. They consist of letters a-z, A-Z and in the future maybe digits 0-9. There can be more than the two parameters x and y.

Maybe just match any query string (providing there is a query string).

Try the following instead:

```
# REDIRECT: /path/?param=a/b/c1/d1/e1?x=1&y=y1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/path/(?:index\.php)?\?param=a/b/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)\?([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^(path)/(?:index\.php)?$ /$1/%1.html?%2 [R=302,L]

# REWRITE: /path/c1/d1/e1.html?x=x1&y=y1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(path)/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)\.html$ $1/index.php?param=a/b/$2?%1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very well structured reply! I've tested the solution but receive a 404 error. When looking for the reason I realized that I probably should have emphasized that x and y are just examples for parameter names, but in reality there can be lots of different parameter names.

The shortest way to describe it may be:

How to mod-rewrite
/fixedpart1/fixedpart2/anything
to
/fixedpart1/?fixedpart2=fixed3/fixed4/anything

... or when index.php takes care of fixed3/fixed4 the simpler version...

How to mod-rewrite
/path/param/anything
to
/path/?param=anything

Comment: Are `x` and `y` single character parameter names? Do param names consist of just letters a-z?

Comment: No, the parameters have more than a single character. They consist of letters a-z, A-Z and in the future maybe digits 0-9. There can be more than the two parameters x and y. Maybe we can take the whole URL with all the parameters and just replace `/path/param/` with `/path/?param=a/b/`? All of these components are fixed strings and whats behind that can stay as it is, matching "anything up to end".

Comment: Thank you! With the updated code, I'm still receiving a 404 error. I'll try to find out why or whats's happening and comment again.

Comment: Where/what is generating the 404? Is the request reaching `index.php`? If not then the above directive is not matching and simply defaulting to an Apache 404. However, if it is reaching `index.php` then your script would seem to be generating the 404, perhaps because it's looking at the wrong(?) elements of the request - because of the rewrite (eg. you can't now use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as you "might" have done before, since this is the requested URL, not the URL being rewritten to)?